# Efficiency of methods on case class versus companion object in Spark & Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, functional-programming, case-class

In Spark & Scala, is it more efficient to put logical methods directly on a case class or into the companion object? For example:

```scala
final case class RichInt(x: Int) {
    def isLarge: Boolean = x > RichInt.largeInt
}

object RichInt {
    private val largeInt: Int = 5
}
```

versus

```scala
final case class SlimInt(x: Int) {}

object SlimInt {
    private val largeInt: Int = 5
    def isLarge(slimInt: SlimInt) : Boolean = {
         slimInt.x > largeInt
     }
}
```

The methods are called differently (`SlimInt.isLarge(slimInt)` versus `richInt.isLarge`), with the latter probably being more intuitive, but is there a significant performance penalty for one pattern versus the other?

Comment: AFAIK calling the method should be faster, but the difference should that small and the **JIT** should do a good job inlining both that it really shouldn't matter. So, unless you have proper evidence of the opposite by doing intensive benchmarking, just go with the one that makes it easier to maintain the code.

Comment: It wouldn't surprise me if eliminating the companion object altogether were desirable in spark, but I don't know. They're going to introduce an annotation to force a member to be "static".

Comment: I heard it is better put methods outside the case class because it reduces the size of encoder. I am not 100% sure.